# Fixed point iteration without contractivity

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $x_0>0$, $a>0$, $b>0$ be given and define
$$x_{n+1}:= a+b x_{n}^{1/4}$$.

**Question:** What is this speed of convergence of $x_n$ to the unique solution $x>0$ of $x=a+bx^{1/4}$?

Lacking contractivity of $x\mapsto a+b x^{1/4}$ I don't see how to apply the usual fixed point iteration theorems.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be asymptotically linear with coefficient $f'(r)=\frac{b}{4} r^{-3/4}$ where $r$ is the solution. One can note that the positive solution is bigger than $b^{4/3}$ (which is the positive solution to the equation when $a=0$), so the coefficient is less than $\frac{1}{4}$ irrespective of $a$ or $b$. The coefficient is also less than $\frac{b a^{-3/4}}{4}$ (what you get by ignoring the $b$ term and then plugging the resulting solution into the derivative). This is a better estimate if $b<a^{3/4}$.

Comment: To clarify, what do you mean by "asymptotically linear"? Linear in what?

Comment: @Julian Linear convergence, as in $|x_{n+1}-r| \leq c|x_n-r|$ if $|x_0-r|$ is small enough, where $0<c<1$.

Comment: But isn't that exponential speed? What you are saying suggests that $|x_n-r|\le c^n$. On the other hand, what if $|x_0-r|$ is not small enough? Is there way to control the convergence speed in this case?

Comment: @Julian "Linear convergence" is a standard term in numerical analysis, it means the error decays *only* exponentially. If $|x_0-r|$ is not small enough then $f'(r)$ doesn't tell you anything and you have to look at the global dynamics of the mapping. When $x_0$ is much too big, in the early stages you get much better results than this. If $x_0$ is much too small, the first step might make it worse, and then either $x_0$ is close enough or else it's much too large again.

Comment: @Julian On the other hand I'm pretty sure something like $x_0=a+b^{3/4}$ is close enough to have no issues anyway.